# binding ng-options with collection of arrays

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angularjs-ng-options

I have collection of arrays like this:

```
   $scope.table = {
   hstep: [1, 2, 3],
   mstep: [1, 5, 10, 15, 25, 30]
   };
```

I want to make a drop down list of these two fields hstep and mstepusing select and ng-options.
Here is the html code for ng-options drop down:

```
   <div class="col-xs-6">
   Hours step is:
   <select class="form-control" ng-model="hstep" ng-options="opt for 
   opt in table.hstep"></select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
   Minutes step is:
   <select class="form-control" ng-model="mstep" ng-options="opt for 
   opt in table.mstep"></select>
   </div>
```

But the problem is when I use the above code , the drop down doesn't work meaning on clicking the drop down, it wont give a list of the items downward.

Can anyone please tell what is wrong with this ng-options syntax?

P.S. i want to place this drop down in a modal window in angular js.

Here is my js code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', 
    ['ngTouch','ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']);


app.controller("MainController",
['$scope','$uibModal',function($scope,$uibModal){

$scope.openModal = function(){
$scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
templateUrl: 'modal.html',
controller :'ModalHandlerController',
 size: 'lg',
 });
 }

 $scope.mytime = new Date();
 $scope.table = {
 hstep: [1, 2, 3],
 mstep: [1, 5, 10, 15, 25, 30]
 };
 $scope.hstep = 1;
 $scope.mstep = 15;
 }]);
```

app.controller("ModalHandlerController",function($scope,$uibModalInstance)

```
{  
 $scope.ok = function(){
 $uibModalInstance.close('save');
 }

 });
```

Comment: any errors in the console

Comment: Your code is fine and should work, maybe another error which block this?

Comment: no errors are there in console. @SachilaRanawaka

Comment: i dont know what is blocking this. Does drop downs work in modal window   ( $uib modal service of angular js)? @FetraR.

Comment: @Surbhi Vyas can you create a plnkr

Comment: Do you define the $scope.table in controller? not in the modal controller? how's your code look?

Comment: I have just shared the js code in the post @SachilaRanawaka

Comment: Please check my js code @FetraR.

Comment: @SurbhiVyas check my answer

Comment: @SurbhiVyas you need to set scope params in open function, or the resolve params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [angular-ui-bootstrap modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal), when you create a modal the scope using in this modal is by default $rootScope, so you wont able to use all scope variable defined in your controller.

doc:

> scope (Type: $scope) - The parent scope instance to be used for the
>   modal's content. Defaults to $rootScope

You need to specify the `scope` to use the controller's scope:

```
$scope.table = {
  hstep: [1, 2, 3],
  mstep: [1, 5, 10, 15, 25, 30]
};
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  scope: $scope /* <----- HERE to use the controller scope */
)}
```

**OR use resolve parameter**

you can pass the data in the `resolve` option parameter

```
$scope.table = {
  hstep: [1, 2, 3],
  mstep: [1, 5, 10, 15, 25, 30]
};
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  resolve: {
    table: function() {
      return $scope.table;
    }
  }
});
```

you can then inject it in your Modal controller:

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, table) {
  $scope.table = table;
});
```

https://embed.plnkr.co/NaR7oUNC65ULJTSaKJBh/

Answer (score 0):

- Please check your angular version.
- please check you have other errors are there in your console window
- please initialize the `hstep` and `mstep` model object as below snippet.

Other-vice your code is perfect.

---

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("appContr",function($scope)
{
 $scope.table = {
   hstep: [1, 2, 3],
   mstep: [1, 5, 10, 15, 25, 30]
   };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appContr">
                   <div class="col-xs-6">
   Hours step is:
   <select class="form-control" ng-init="hstep=table.hstep[0]" ng-model="hstep" ng-options="opt for 
   opt in table.hstep"></select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
   Minutes step is:
   <select class="form-control" ng-init="mstep=table.mstep[0]"  ng-model="mstep" ng-options="opt for 
   opt in table.mstep"></select>
   </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: my angular version is 1.6.2 and i want to place this drop-down inside a modal window($uib modal service).